# Getting NullPointerException while adding element to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Percolation {
    ArrayList<int[]> grid;
    Random dice = new Random();
    public Percolation(int n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            grid.add(new int[n]);
        }
        output(grid,n);
    }

    public void output(ArrayList<int[]> x,int n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                System.out.println(x.get(i)[j]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Percolation p = new Percolation(2);
    }
}
```

Using this code throws a `NullPointerException` at `grid.add(new int[n])`. How can I add data to `grid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialize the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<int[]> grid = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Percolation {
 ArrayList<int[]> grid = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize the array List here before using
 Random dice = new Random();
 public Percolation(int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        grid.add(new int[n]);
    }
    output(grid,n);
}

public void output(ArrayList<int[]> x,int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            System.out.println(x.get(i)[j]);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Percolation p = new Percolation(2);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without initialization you can not add element in list.

And you can also pass another `ArrayList` in `<>` e.g.:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> grid = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because it is much dynamic.